# What rectangular object would is this Boer War era officer carrying on his left hand side?

Tags: victorian

The screenshots are from [32:34](https://youtu.be/yCDJSVmxHkg?t=1954). This scene portrays [Lt Col Philip Robert Anstruther](http://www.thepeerage.com/p12359.htm#i123585) at the [Battle of Bronkhorstspruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Bronkhorstspruit), played by [Kerry Jordan](http://aor.theavengers.tv/bio_kerry_jordan.htm).

I know this is a movie, but what rectangular object are my green arrows marking? If you watch the scene, you can see it swinging?

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find a photo for the uniform in 1880, but this looks like a document and maps case (like the one in https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/British_Military_Records#/media/File:British_Military2.jpg) and they looked like this in 1870: https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/victorian-leather-clad-document-seal-168631824

Comment: I too would suspect a map/despatch case. Difficult to tell, but not sure it's attached to his hand, which would be a bad idea in close combat, but to his uniform.

Comment: It looks as though the props department had no idea either.  Whatever it is, it's been slung dangerously low.  Is Lt Col Anstruther going to shoot himself or stab himself when he next trips over it?

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a document/map case, as noted in comments. The style changed over time, but was a staple of every officer's kit. I doubt very much that it is tied to the officer's hand. It is more likely slung over his shoulder, and he has grabbed it momentarily to keep it from swinging.

[World Was Two style](https://www.ima-usa.com/products/original-british-wwii-officer-map-case-wwii-dated?variant=25650880133)

[image]

[image: World War Two style British officer's document & map case - interior]

[World War One style](https://stewartsmilitaryantiques.com/us-or-british-wwi-pattern-officers-canvas-map-case.29648.archive.htm)

[image: World War One style British officer's document & map case - exterior]

[image: World War One style British officer's document & map case - interior]

Other styles of map cases, of various eras, from [Australia's Museums Victoria collections](https://museumsvictoria.com.au/):

- [WW1 Army](https://victoriancollections.net.au/items/5a5eb38590751a15e8474675)
- [Circa 1916](https://victoriancollections.net.au/items/5b31da6121ea6a176c97ec58)
- [WW2](https://victoriancollections.net.au/items/58194e5bd0cdd11ed4e641fe)
- [Modern](https://victoriancollections.net.au/items/5308228b2162ef1fb8b256a4)
- [Unspecified vintage](https://victoriancollections.net.au/items/5b07b97521ea6b03ac422f02)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a [sabretache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabretache).

[image]

The Royal Horse Artillery still use them for ceremonial events but whether they used them in the field during the Boer War I don't know. That also assumes this is meant to be an artillery officer. It is certainly only something a person who usually moves around on horseback would wear given how low to the ground it hangs.

I suspect this sabretache has been conflated with the dispatch/map pouch already mentioned as is a mistake by the costume department.